# How to count the numeric values from cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in cell like.

```
1,2,4,45,64,Jan. Ans: 5
```

I want to count only number from the cell.
Is it possible?

Comment: while [COUNT](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNT-function-A59CD7FC-B623-4D93-87A4-D23BF411294C) should help, your `Jan` may be a number with a `MMM` formatting... it is not completely clear what you have and need.... can you specify you question a bit?

Comment: or post a sample screenshot of your data ...

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `split` function in a UDF:

```
Function CountNumbers(R As Range) As Integer
  Dim values, value As Variant
  Dim result As Integer

  values = Split(R.Text, ",")
  result = 0

  For Each value In values
    If IsNumeric(value) Then
      result = result + 1
    End If
  Next value

  CountNumbers = result

End Function
```

From here, you could call it within another Excel cell as:

```
=CountNumbers(A1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my answer:

```
Sub countingNumbers()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim L As Long
    Dim s As String
    Dim tmp
    Dim i
    Dim y
    Set c = Range("A1") 'Imagine in A1 is this: "RDFY2372784GDTD2GV3G3G3V3"
    L = Len(c.Value) 'to store the len of the string
    s = c.Value 'to store the string
    y = 0 'the index of the numbers
    For i = 1 To L
        tmp = Left(Right(s, i), 1) 'to take just one letter at the time
        If Asc(tmp) < 57 And Asc(tmp) > 48 Then
        'if is a number ASC() returns the ASCII code of that number
        'and increase y one by one || that is number by number
            y = y + 1
        End If
    Next i
    Range("B2").Value = y 'store the counting in B2
End Sub


Part of the ASCII Table:
+------------+-----------+
| ASCII Code | Character |
+------------+-----------+
|         48 | 0         |
|         49 | 1         |
|         50 | 2         |
|         51 | 3         |
|         52 | 4         |
|         53 | 5         |
|         54 | 6         |
|         55 | 7         |
|         56 | 8         |
|         57 | 9         |
|         64 | @         |
|         65 | A         |
|         66 | B         |
|         67 | C         |
|         68 | D         |
|         69 | E         |
|         70 | F         |
|         71 | G         |
|         72 | H         |
|         73 | I         |
|         74 | J         |
+------------+-----------+
```

Here you can check the [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) table

Comment: This would count the numerical characters inside the cell... at least 1 to 8, cus 0 and 9 would not be count by your code. A simple `IsNumeric(Mid(c.Value,i,1)` would be easier... while this could also be done easiely without VBA by an array-formula like this: `=SUM(IF(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),ISNUMBER(MID(A1,ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1)*1)*1))`